# I want to run a project and see how it appears on my browser but I get errors

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am trying to use `npm start` to the project to see it run on my browser.

It gives me following errors:

```
PS C:\Users\JUSTIN\Documents\GitHub\myPortfolio> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages       
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\JUSTIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-19T06_04_59_628Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\JUSTIN\Documents\GitHub\myPortfolio> npm install-script
```

Comment: can you give me the entire content of package.json?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Missing script: "start"

This most likely the issue. Check the package.json file for a script named "start", it may not be there. Alternatively, try `npm run start`.